# Split a string with delimiter and assign to new key - logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, split, logstash, kibana, data-ingestion

I am trying to import csv into elasticsearch using logstash.
I have a field in the csv with is an IP:Port pair. I would like to split the IP and port, and assign them to two new keys though the logstash config file.

I looked into kv , but kv seems to require the keys and values pair in the string. Mine is only value.

Sample csv data:

`hostname1,172.20.28.11:8080,proxy_web,false
 hostname2,172.20.28.20:443,web_https,false`

In the above case, I already map the second field as "IP_Port" (using csv=> column)
Now, I want to split 172.20.28.11:8080 as IP=172.20.28.11 and port=8080 (key=IP,value=172.20.28.11) and alike for port. Then mutate the datatype for the IP as 'ip datatype'.

After that, I can include the IP to geoip conversion using the following snippet, if I want to convert that extracted IP and use it to do geomapping.

```
geoip {
    source => "Source IP" 
    target => "geoip" 
    database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat" 
    add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ] 
    add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ] 
}
mutate {
    convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"] 
}
```

Any suggestions on this?